# has_many of itself though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm working on a maze project in rails, and ironically, I got lost. So far, I'm pretty new with has_many_though relationships between models, so what if a model has many of itself through something ?

Basically, Each `Room` has many `Rooms`. I created a `Tunnel` model to connect these rooms, so that a room is connected to many others through tunnels. But it gets trickier when it comes to building these relations.

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :tunnels
  has_many :rooms, through: :tunnels

end
```

And my Tunnel gets to connect two rooms

```
class Tunnel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lemmin_room, :foreign_key => "room1_id"
  belongs_to :lemmin_room, :foreign_key => "room2_id"
end
```

Rails documentation is pretty clear when it comes toe ModelA has many Model B through ModelC, but I don't think it ever mentions ModelA = ModelB.

Comment: Is this relationship one-directional (a room has many other rooms through a tunnel, but perhaps if I am in one of those connected rooms I can't go back to the previous room through the same tunnel?) or is it a mirrored relationship (a room A connected to another room B can be got to from B via the same tunnel)?

Comment: I can go back to the previous room by the same tunnel if needed, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define two `belongs_to` association with different name, like:

```
class Tunnel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lemmin_room_1, :foreign_key => "room1_id"
  belongs_to :lemmin_room_2, :foreign_key => "room2_id"
end
```

Then, in your `Room` model:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tunnels
  has_many :rooms, through: :tunnels, source: :lemmin_room_1
end
```

You can specify `source` to get what rooms you want in `Tunnel`.